# repeat array going up and down in with some limit

Tags: javascript, arrays, limit

I have data in this form `[1,2,3,4]`. I want to perform some operation on this array so that I will get output like this `[1,2,3,4, 4,3,2,1, 1,2]`. Please, can you suggest some way for me to achieve this output?

```
// function declaration 

function arrayExm(array,limit){ 
  // want some operations here so that i will get this output
}

//function execution 

arrayExm([1,2,3,4],10) 
//so it will return [1,2,3,4, 4,3,2,1, 1,2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it using a simple for loop.

```js
function arrayExm(array, limit) {
  var res = [],
    len = array.length;

  // iterate upto the limit
  for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    // define the value based on the iteration 
    res[i] = Math.floor(i / len) % 2 == 0 ? // check the array element repetition is odd or even
      array[i % len] : // if even define element in same order   
      array[len - i % len - 1]; // if odd define element in reverse order
  }

  return res;
};



console.log(arrayExm([1, 2, 3, 4], 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just **concat()** your array and its **reverse()** as long as you limit parameter enable you to take an entire array and at the end you will **slice()** part of the array it will remain

```js
var arrayReapet = (array, limit) => {
  var results = [];
  var divisor = parseInt(limit / array.length);
  var modulo = limit % array.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < divisor; i++) {
    if (i === 0) results = results.concat(array);
    else results = results.concat(array.reverse());
  }
  results = results.concat(array.reverse().slice(0, modulo));
  return results
}

console.log(arrayReapet([1, 2, 3, 4], 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a generator to generate the back-and-forth sequences. Then write another generator to take the first *n* values.

```js
function* repeat(arr) {
  const rev = arr.slice().reverse();

  while (true) {
    for (let x of arr) yield x;  // Up...
    for (let x of rev) yield x;  // and down...
  }
}

function* take(iterable, n) {
  for (let x of iterable) if (!n--) return; else yield x;
}

console.log([...take(repeat([1,2,3,4]), 10)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it will helpful for you, In this code you can start the array arrangement in both forward and backward direction by giving true(forward) and false(backward). Even array contains string also you can arrange by using this code.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var outputArray = [];
var j = 0;
var i;
arrayRepeat(array, 10, true);


alert(outputArray);

function arrayRepeat(array, limit, direction) {

  if (direction) {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length, j < limit; i++, j++) {
      outputArray[j] = array[i];
      if (i == array.length) {
        arrayRepeat(array, limit, false);
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (i = array.length - 1; i >= 0, j < limit; i--, j++) {
      outputArray[j] = array[i];
      if (i == -1) {
        arrayRepeat(array, limit, true);
      }
    }
  }
}
```